# Comparison of two data sets in SAS

Tags: sas

I have the following data set:

```
data data_one;
length X 3
Y $ 20; 

input x y ;

datalines;
1 test
2 test
3 test1
4 test1
5 test
6 test
7 test1

    run;

data data_two;
length Z 3
       A $ 20;

input Z A;

datalines;
1 test
2 test1
3 test2
run;
```

What I would like to have is a data set which tells me how often column Y in data_one contains the same string of column A in data_two. The result should look like this one:

```
 Obs    test    test1    test2

  1       4       3        0
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to start showing what code you have tried in your questions.  We are not here to do your work for you, but are often happy to help solve the problems you encounter when you trying to figure it out for yourself.

Comment: I'm not so concerned about 'showing work' per se, but about the question being too much of a "do this complete task" rather than asking about a specific thing the asker isn't sure about.  This question might well be a perfectly reasonable question, if asked differently, but the way it's asked means it's not.

Comment: First of all sorry for not giving any examples of what I tried. The think is that I m pretty new in SAS. My Idea was to build an array or something filled with column A and then somehow work with a 'do' loop and 'contain'. But it did not work and maybe was total rubbish so I did not post it. But thank you for advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First we need the counts for those values of Y present in data_one.
2. Then we create a sorted (for the next merge) list of the values present in data_two.
3. The data_one Y counts from 1. are merged with the list from 2.
   The Y values present in data_two but not in data_one `(b and not a)` are assigned count=0, the Y values not present in data_two are discarded (`if b`).
4. The last passage transposes the vertical list of counts in an horizontal set of variables.

---

```
proc freq data=data_one noprint;
    table y / out=count_one (keep=y count);
run;
proc sort data=data_two out=list_two (keep=a rename=(a=y)) nodupkey;
    by a;
run;
data count_all;
    merge count_one (in=a) list_two (in=b);
    by y;
    if (b and not a) then count=0;
    if b;
run;
proc transpose data=count_all out=final (drop=_name_ _label_);
    id y;
run;
```

---

The first 3 steps can be replaced with one proc SQL:

```
proc sql;
    create table count_all as
    select distinct
            coalesce(t1.y,t2.a) as y,
            case
                when missing(t1.y) then 0 
                else count(t1.y)
            end as N
        from data_one as t1
        right join data_two as t2
            on t1.y=t2.a
        group by 1
        order by 1;
quit;
proc transpose data=count_all out=final (drop=_name_);
    id y;
run;
```

Comment: I edited the code to add `if b;` in the data step, so to exclude those values of Y present in data_one but not in data_two (not present in your example but possible).

Comment: Code dumps aren't generally considered good answers.  The OP should be asking "How do I do X", not "Do X for me"; so while sometimes the code is part of the answer, the more important part of it should be explaining how.

Comment: @Joe you're perfectly right, I'll add some text to describe the process